# Android/QR-Code: Is it possible open directly the Google Play Store using a QR Code?

Tags: android, qr-code

I have published a simple application on the Google Play Store. Now i need to create a qr-code that when is read open directly the page of my application on the Play Store. Is it possible do it? In fact actually, i have created a qr-code for test, but everytime the device read it, a little box appear and ask me if i want open the link with Chrome, Browser or Play Store. Can i avoid the show of this box and go directly to the Play Store?

Thanks

Comment: The uri is parsed by every application that can use it! You have to specify a market uri if you want the Play Store to open it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make a QR code out of the link

```
market://details?id=com.example.your.package
```

A normal `http://` URI can be processed by multiple apps. However, the `market://` scheme is used by Google Play, and normal browsers will not respond to it

Comment: and for iOS App Store?